# How about intel native lib inside an android javafxport apk

Tags: javafxports

I see that inside generated apk, in lib directory there are only armeabi native shared libs. I try to install it on intel-atom android emulator, but installing I have this error:

```
adb install d:\Mypack.apk
[100%] /data/local/tmp/Mypack.apk
        pkg: /data/local/tmp/Mypack.apk
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS]

In lib\armeaby there are these .so:
libactivity.so
libdecora_sse.so
libglass_monocle.so
libjavafx_font.so
libjavafx_font_freetype.so
libjavafx_iio.so
libprism_common.so
libprism_es2_monocle.so
libwebview.so
```

So, does javafxports support intel architecture on android? 
May be I need a translator on emulator ?
Please help. Thanks

Comment: It is a known [issue](https://bitbucket.org/javafxports/android/issues/65/emulator). So far, BlueStacks is your best option.

Comment: Thanks, Jose' . I try blue Stacks, it 's an alternative.