# Deploying to an Android emulator shows error INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS

Tags: mobile, javafx, gluon

My app has a plugin [KeyboardService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40801771/textfield-in-a-container-keyboard-hides-text/40823146#40823146) for iOS. Now i want to use the same app on android. Deploying on an emulator gives me the error INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS which says its the wrong architecture.

Is the error because of my plugin which is only for iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are already some questions regarding the use of Android emulators. This [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41834180/how-about-intel-native-lib-inside-an-android-javafxport-apk) points to the [issue](https://bitbucket.org/javafxports/android/issues/65/emulator) you are facing.

So far, your best option for an emulator, in case you don't have a real Android device, is using BlueStacks.